# Using oAuth with Twitter in ShareKit - High Permission Level?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, sdk, sharekit

I am using Sharekit to post a couple of lines of text from my app to twitter. I am using oAuth and have chosen "Read and Write" permission when setting up the app in twitter.

When I post to twitter, the app works perfectly and asks me to validate my login. However I notice it says the following :

> This application will be able to :
>
> - Read tweets from your timeline
> - See who you follow and follow new people
> - Update your profile (!)
> - Post tweets on your behalf

Is this normal - it strikes me as odd that the user is agreeing to me being able to change his profile and follow users on his behalf ?

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct, read/write on your app provides all these permissions to it. You'd wonder why they'd have a separate permission for DMs and only DMs...